# how handle multiple select input box to handle same jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked for answers on here and have not found anything that directly can help me so I am going to ask here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sel").change(function() {
    var hh = $('.sel').val();
    if(hh == "info")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "#333");
    }
    if(hh == "green")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "green");
    }
    if(hh == "red")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "red");
    }
    if(hh == "orange")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "orange");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
select.sel
{
  border:0;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;   
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>  
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select> 
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>
```

This is running perfectly when there is single select input but when i use multiple select input box .. 
this code is not working ... plz help ..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: use `$(this).val()` instead of `var hh = $('.sel').val();`

Comment: thanks :) it's worked

Comment: cool... glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of select inside onchange event please use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(".sel").val()`.

As such `$(".sel").val()` will give value of first select element always. And `$(this).val()` will give value of current changes select box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sel").change(function() {
    var hh = $(this).val();
    if(hh == "info")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "#333");
    }
    if(hh == "green")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "green");
    }
    if(hh == "red")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "red");
    }
    if(hh == "orange")
    {
      $(this).css("color" , "orange");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
select.sel
{
  border:0;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;   
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>  
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select> 
<select class="sel">
  <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
  <option value="green">Present</option>
  <option value="red">Absent</option>
  <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @AnkitJain welcome dude. Please accept my answer if it does helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a value of the current select only (use ***$(this).val()***). A working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sel").change(function() {
      // Take value of a current select element
      var hh = $(this).val();
      if(hh == "info")
      {
        $(this).css("color" , "#333");
      }
      if(hh == "green")
      {
        $(this).css("color" , "green");
      }
      if(hh == "red")
      {
        $(this).css("color" , "red");
      }
      if(hh == "orange")
      {
        $(this).css("color" , "orange");
      }
      
});
});
```

```css
select.sel
{
    border:0;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;   
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
            <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
            <option value="green">Present</option>
            <option value="red">Absent</option>
            <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>  
<select class="sel">
            <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
            <option value="green">Present</option>
            <option value="red">Absent</option>
            <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select> 
<select class="sel">
            <option selected value="info">Not Taken</option>
            <option value="green">Present</option>
            <option value="red">Absent</option>
            <option value="orange">Late</option>
</select>
```